# Is redirecting to another controller action on an ajax request going to be recognized by the browser?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

Right now, I have a rails ajax request on submission of a form, which has the following success code:

```
if @event.save
  ...
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js { render 'draw_calendar' }
    format.html { redirect_to show_calendar_path }
  end
end
```

I need to add some code that, if a new flag is set on the form, will spawn the creation of a new, follow-up form for a different model that (of course) should be governed by a different controller. Thus what I want to do is, if `@event` gets saved successfully, check that flag (easy), and if it's set, redirect to another controller action. First, will that even work in the browser if it was an ajax request (format.js)? And second, will the browser then successfully render whatever gets sent back from the new controller action?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, browser always follow redirect in ajax request

```
if @event.save
  if @event.something?
    redirect_to some_other_path(format: params[:format])
    return
  end
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js { render 'draw_calendar' }
    format.html { redirect_to show_calendar_path }
  end
end
```

If you need to detect redirect in javascript code I usually add custom header

```
response.headers['X-XHR-Current-Location'] = request.fullpath
```

Comment: And what if the redirect returns javascript rather than HTML (as it will if the original request was ajax). Will the browser automatically handle that or do I need to do something special?

Comment: Just try to make it, I think it should be fine. Ajax request can return anything